# How to fetch data dynamically from JSON file on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have created an artist(artists.html) page, which includes around 15 artists. Now I am trying to create the profile of each artist through one single HTML file dynamically. So I have created another HTML file(single-artist.html) which will show the profile of an artist clicked by the visitor.

artists.html (Out of 15 artists, below are the two examples)

```
    <div class="all-artist" id="artists">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 artist-single" data-number="0">
                <div>
                    <a href="artist-single.html">
                        <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div> 

            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 artist-single" data-number="1">
                <div>
                    <a href="artist-single.html">
                        <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="">
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>

    </div>
```

artist-single.html

```
<div id="name"></div>
<div id="logo"></div>
<div id="bio"></div>
```

data.json

```
[{

"name": "Arsh",
"logo": "img/logo.jpg", 
"bio": "Arsh is a singer/songwriter"

},

{

"name": "Benz",
"logo": "img/logo.jpg", 
"bio": "Benz is a singer"

}]
```

main.js

```
  $('#all_artists artist-single').on('click',function(){
window.location.href="artist-single.html";
var num = $(this).data('number');
$.getJSON('data.json',function(data) {
    $('#name').html(data[num].name);
    $('#description').html(data[num].bio);
    $('#logo').append('<img src=data[num].logo>');
  });
});
```

Now, when I click on an artist image, it redirects to artist-single.html but it's not fetching values. Maybe because I am redirecting and fetching the values on the same event. Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: The code running after the redirect will be aborted. You should perform that part in a document ready function on the other page.

Comment: You'll need to wait until new page will be loaded.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589401/changing-window-location-then-waiting-for-the-window-to-load

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var num = $.cookie('num');

  $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
    $('#name').html(data[num].name);
    $('#description').html(data[num].bio);
    $('#logo').append('<img src=data[num].logo>');
  });

  $('#artists .artist-single').on('click', function() {
    var num = $(this).data('number');
    $.cookie('num', num);
    window.location.href = "artist-single.html";
  });

});
```

Comment: Hey William, thanks for the answer but I am afraid it's still not working.